# Google Earth Engine chart won’t create at 30m scale

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart, reduceregion

I used Google Earth Engine to classify an image and now want to display the fraction of the image occupied by each training class in a chart. However, I am getting the error returned as:

> "Image.reduceRegion: Too many pixels in the region. Found 52163252, but maxPixels allows only 10000000. Ensure that you are not aggregating at a higher resolution than you intended; that is a frequent cause of this error. If not, then you may set the 'maxPixels' argument to a limit suitable for your computation; set 'bestEffort' to true to aggregate at whatever scale results in 'maxPixels' total pixels; or both."

I have tried to vary the scale until it finally returns a chart, and that happens when the scale is at 75m, although I want the chart to be printed at 30m scale. I specified a higher `maxPixel` value and also a `bestEffort` parameter to `true` but it still isn't plotting at 30m.

What adjustment can I make to resolve the error, so the chart is created at the scale of 30m?
The Hrst study area asset is at https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/Bongy/Hearst

The portion where the code fails is below:

```
// Area of study area:
var CBArea = Hrst.geometry().area() 
var CBAreaSqKm = ee.Number(CBArea).divide(1e6).round()
print(CBAreaSqKm, 'Total CB ara')
print(CBArea, 'Sq m CB ara')

// Now that each pixel per class in the image has the value equal to its area, we can sum up all the values in the region
// CHART RESULTS:
var options = {
  lineWidth: 1,
  pointSize: 2,
  hAxis: {title: 'Classes'},
  vAxis: {title: 'Area m^2'},
  title: 'Area by class',
  series: {
    0: { color: 'red'},
    1: { color: 'green'},
    2: { color: 'purple'},
    3: { color: 'pink'},
    4: { color: 'black'},
    5: { color: 'blue'},
    6: { color: 'brown'}
  }
};

// Using a reducer.
print(ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(classified).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
    groupField: 1, 
    groupName: 'classification'
  }), 
  geometry: Hrst.geometry(), 
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  bestEffort: true,
  scale: 30 //     
}))
var areaChart = ui.Chart.image.byClass({
  image: ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(classified),
  classBand: 'classification', 
  region: Hrst.geometry(),
  scale: 30,
  classLabels: ['Building', 'Mixed', 'Decid', 'Road', 'Conif', 'Water', 'Crops'],
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum()
}).setOptions(options)
  .setSeriesNames(['Building', 'Mixed', 'Decid', 'Road', 'Conif', 'Water', 'Crops']);  
print(areaChart);
```